# Identify original call from QDBusPendingCallWatcher in catch-all callback

Tags: c++, qt, dbus

I want to use Qt's `QDBusPendingCallWatcher` to keep track of the response of some D-Bus calls. There are several different D-Bus calls I can make, but I want to have a single callback for all of them.

The problem is that the `finished` signal that `QDBusPendingCallWatcher` emits when the return value is ready only has a pointer to `QDBusPendingCallWatcher` itself, and I have found no way of getting the original `QDBusMessage` (which contains the method that was called).

Digging deep in to Qt's source code you can see that calling `asyncCall` creates the `QDBusMessage` which is in turn passed to the `QDBusConnection` being used, but sadly the info is stored using the pimpl pattern in `QDBusPendingCallPrivate` and seems to be impossible to recover from client code.

TL;DR: Would it be possible to know the method name of an async D-Bus call from within the slot fired by the `QDBusPendingCallWatcher::finished` signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found out, it seems that there's no way to get the original message back.  However, there's at least two work-arounds that I can see.  Since `QDbusPendingCallWatcher` inherits from `QObject`, you can set a property on the watcher that keeps the name of the method call around.  Or, you could have a lambda function that adds in more information to the callback(e.g. the method name).

```
DBusCaller::DBusCaller(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    QDBusInterface connSettings("org.freedesktop.NetworkManager",                                    "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1",                              
"org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings.Connection",
                            QDBusConnection::systemBus() );

    //Method 1: set a property on the object
    {
        QDBusPendingCall pending = connSettings.asyncCall( "GetSettings" );
        QDBusPendingCallWatcher* watch = new QDBusPendingCallWatcher( pending );
        watch->setProperty( "method", "GetSettings" );
        connect( watch, &QDBusPendingCallWatcher::finished,
             this, &DBusCaller::callFinished );
    }

    //Method 2: use a lambda to add more information to our callback
    {
        QString methodName = "GetSettings";
        QDBusPendingCall pending = connSettings.asyncCall( methodName );
        QDBusPendingCallWatcher* watch = new QDBusPendingCallWatcher( pending );
        connect( watch, &QDBusPendingCallWatcher::finished,
             this, [=](QDBusPendingCallWatcher* reply) { callFinishedString( methodName, reply ); });
    }
}

void DBusCaller::callFinished(QDBusPendingCallWatcher* pending){
    pending->deleteLater();
    qDebug() << "Pending finished.  Method: " << pending->property( "method" );
}

void DBusCaller::callFinishedString(QString methodName, 
QDBusPendingCallWatcher *watch){
    watch->deleteLater();
    qDebug() << "Pending finsihed.  Method: " << methodName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, what a detailed explanation. I ended up doing something similar to the second approach and works very well. A+!